# "The earth was believed to be flat "

Tags: passive-voice

I think I couldn't understand what would it mean/imply if I change tenses in this sentence..

Does they make any sense   or are they grammatically correct?

"The earth was believed to be flat "

"The earth was believed to was flat "

"The earth was believed to have been flat "

"The earth is believed to be flat " (People think the Eath is still flat? )

"The earth is believed to was flat "

"The earth is believed to have been flat "

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The earth was believed to be flat.*  - People thought "The earth is flat".

*The earth was believed to was flat.* - Ungrammatical

*The earth was believed to have been flat* - People thought "The earth was / used to be flat".

*The earth is believed to be flat.*  - People think "The earth is  flat".

*The earth is believed to was flat.*  - Ungrammatical

.

There is no form 'to was' in English.

Comment: @ tunny Thank you for your answer.It helps a lot me to figure out what could they mean. "The earth is believed to have been flat "  implies people still think that it is true the earth was flat many years ago but not anymore?

Comment: @Murat. You are right.